# Create an array of mixed objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create an array like this one:

```
["Apple",{1: "Pie", 2: "Dumpling", 3: "Cider"}, "Banana", {1: "Bread", 2: "Republic"}]
```

starting from an array of just:

```
["Apple", "Banana"]

// <input id="Apple"... data-makes="Pie,Dumpling,Cider"> 
// <input id="Banana" ... data-makes="Bread,Republic"

var output = [];
var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana"];
for (i=0; i < fruits.length; ++i)
{
  members = document.getElementById(fruits[i]).getAttribute("data-makes");
  tmp = members.split(",");
  for (k=0; k < tmp.length; ++k)
  {
    output[i][k+1] = tmp[k];
  }
}
```

Everything I've tried so far is either invalid syntax or makes the initial array *undefined*.

Comment: Can you add your HTML for the elements with `data-makes`

Comment: @Andy also the desired array is 1-D but OP is creating a 2D array `output[i][k+1] = tmp[k];`

Comment: Shouldn't the result be more like this: ["Apple",["Pie","Dumpling","Cider"], "Banana", ["Bread","Republic"]]

Comment: it should be more like => {"Apple":["Pie","Dumpling","Cider"],"Banana":["Bread","Republic"]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try something like this. You will have to replace the hard coded elements...

```js
var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana"];
var tempString = "Pie,Dumpling,Cider";
var tempArray = new Array();
tempArray.push(tempString);
tempString = "Bread,Republic";
tempArray.push(tempString);
var output = {};
for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++)
{
    var members = tempArray[i].split(",");
    var temp = {};
    for(var k = 0; k < members.length; k++)
    {
        temp[("" + k)] = members[k];
    }
    output[("" + fruits[i])] = temp;
}
console.log(output);
//Different ways to access the objects
console.log(output.Apple);
console.log(output["Apple"]);
console.log(output.Banana[0]);
console.log(output["Banana"]["0"]);
```

[image]

Comment: Hooray! Chrome Developer Tools user! ;)

Comment: Looks good. I would never have figured out that syntax on my own. Your example outputs exactly like my hand made data object does in the console! I'll code my actual code like this and then come back and mark this correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative method you might find useful in the future.

```
// loop over the fruits
var arr = fruits.reduce(function (fp, fc) {

  // get the string (in your example the data-makes value)
  // and add each to a new object
  var temp = makes[fc].split(', ').reduce(function (p, c, i) {
    p[i + 1] = c;
    return p;
  }, {});

  // then concatenate the fruit name and its object to
  // the output array
  return fp.concat.apply(fp, [fc, temp]);
}, []);
```

OUTPUT

```
[
  "Apple", { "1": "pie", "2": "dumpling", "3": "cider"},
  "Banana", { "1": "bread", "2": "Republic" }
]
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ezzk4tmr/1/)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana"], i, k, members, tmp, output = [];
  var final = [];
    for (i=0; i < fruits.length; ++i)
    {
      members = document.getElementById(fruits[i]).getAttribute("data-makes");
      tmp = members.split(",");
      output[i] = new Object();
      for (k=0; k < tmp.length; ++k)
      {
         output[i][k+1] = tmp[k];
      }
      final.push(fruits[i])
      final.push(output[i])
    }
   console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, remember that JSON keys are always Strings -- no integers.

```
["Apple", "Banana"]

// data-makes="Pie,Dumpling,Cider", data-makes="Bread,Republic"
var output = [];
var type;
var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana"];
for (i=0; i < fruits.length; ++i)
{
  members = document.getElementById(fruits[i]).getAttribute("data-makes");
  tmp = members.split(",");
  for (k=0; k < tmp.length; ++k)
  {
    type = {}
    type[fruits[i]] = {}
    type[fruits[i]][k] = tmp[k]
    output.push(type);
  }
}
```

This will output:

```
[
 { "apple" : {
               "1" : "pie",
               "2" : "Dumpling",
               "3" : "Cider"
             } 
  },
  { "banana" : {
               "1" : "Bread",
               "2" : "Republic"
             }
]
```

Not exactly what you asked (I can't imagine the use of a 1-D array for this, but you can get the point)

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in your code:

First, you're never putting `fruits[i]` in the `output` array.

Second, you can't assign to `output[i][k+1]` until you first initialize `output[i]` to be an array or object.

```
for (i=0; i < fruits.length; ++i)
{
  output.push(fruits[i]);
  var members = document.getElementById(fruits[i]).getAttribute("data-makes");
  var tmp = members.split(",");
  var obj = {};
  for (k=0; k < tmp.length; ++k)
  {
    obj[k+1] = tmp[k];
  }
  output.push(obj);
}
```